# Getting Error on running SQL Query in Android with substring function

Tags: android, sql, database, android-sqlite

```
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id as id, amount as amt, category, date from expense where userid=? and substr(date,0,4)=? and substr(date, 5, 1) order by _id desc", new String[]{String.valueOf(id), ySelected, mSelected});
```

Getting FATAL Error at this query
The query is running fine without substr function. I need to add the condition on the sub-part of text in the column. Can anybody help?

Error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.smdproj, PID: 13094
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.smdproj/com.example.smdproj.viewExp}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 3 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 2 parameters.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3408)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3547)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:140)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2080)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:264)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7581)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:980)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 3 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 2 parameters.
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bind(SQLiteProgram.java:215)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindString(SQLiteProgram.java:169)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindAllArgsAsStrings(SQLiteProgram.java:203)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:49)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1443)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1382)
        at com.example.smdproj.viewExp.onCreate(viewExp.java:171)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7805)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7794)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1306)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3378)
```

Comment: The way you are using substring() is not  what you expect its doing. you are actualy substing  the string date its self. substr(date, 5, 1) will error of course becuse you are asking substr to extract a string from date starting from index 5 but date is only 4 characters.

Comment: `and substr(date, 5, 1)` there's a missing comparison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you miss "=?" in the third condition in your query.

```
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id as id, amount as amt, category, date from expense where userid=? and substr(date,0,4)=? and substr(date, 5, 1)=? order by _id desc", new String[]{String.valueOf(id), ySelected, mSelected});
```